# FQL get all photos from album

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I'm using `FBRequestConnection` on iPhone for getting all photos from same album.
I want to get all photos from album which has 11 photos in it and `aid="100001996111955_72360"`.
I wrote the below code, but it returned 4 photos, not 11.

```sql
SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid="100001996111955_72360"
```

Can anyone enlighten me why I couldn't get all the photos?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Comment: Yes, you are right Prince, but it does not work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

When I run your FQL query in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20pid%2C%20src_big%20FROM%20photo%20WHERE%20aid%3D%22100001996111955_72360%22), I get 11 items returned. There must be another problem in your script if you are only seeing 4 items.

Another comment: `pid` and `aid` are on the path to deprecation. To future proof your script, you should be using `object_id` wherever possible.

```
SELECT object_id, src_big FROM photo WHERE album_object_id = 313997665343435
```

(`SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE aid="100001996111955_72360"` = 313997665343435)

Comment: Thanks for answer. It turns out the request was correct. I added some user data permissions, and then to take all photos.

Comment: Would be nice to write down which ones and why...